# Fire Jquery event when i change one of the 10 select lists

Tags: jquery

I have `n` number of select lists. `n` is dynamic ( depends on the condition and range of n is 1-30). I want to run a jQuery function with `.change()` event. Please tell me how can I do that.

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assign same class to all your select lists, say "`demo`", and use [on change](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler:'

```
$(document).on('change', '.demo', function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to give class to all your dropdowns. you can use that class to sence the change event.  like

```
$('.dropdown').change(function(){
});
```

hope this will help.